# IntelliJ CE cannot load ~/.aws/credentials file using Smart Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to simply run Tomcat in IntelliJ. Since I am using IntelliJ CE, I am trying the Smart Tomcat plugin. It runs, but it cannot find my aws credentials which I have both in my maven file and in the ~/.aws/credentials file. Do I need any VM args? How else can I help this program find the files? Maven is able to load from the maven files fine.

Comment: How do you configure the "Tomcat Server" drop-down?  It's not asking for the Tomcat Installation bin folder and you can't write in the answer, so what is passed into that?  Thanks,

Comment: I passed in the path to my Tomcat folder I installed. I was not sure either..